# Google shortcuts for Android

Tags: java, android, translate

Hi I am trying to get the url for google translate as a shortcut so as it automatically searches for the word in the input box.  It works on the pc but does not work on Emulator.

For example if I type in `"http://translate.google.com/?hl=en&tab=wT#auto|en|hello"` on firefox or chrome it goes straight to the input box and translates "hello".  But when I do it on the emulator it does not put the word in the input box.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add `vi=c` to the URL so you get the 'classic' version of Google Translate, not the Mobile version which behaves differently.

```
http://translate.google.com/?vi=c&hl=en&tab=wT#auto|en|hello
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply but it doesn't put the word in the input box, in fact in the emulator I typed it in manually and it would not let me past the **|en|** part......I tried shortening the link with **bit.ly**, but that does not allow you to add extra word on to that link then, thats what I need you see for my search not just hello.